# "Incorrect syntax" error when running SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert into database using this class, I am able to access this class in My Customer page, but getting error

> Incorrect syntax near '@ZipCode'.

Meanwhile I don't have any stored procedure or trigger in my SQL Server database.

```
public class CustomerDLL
{
    SqlConnection cn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;

    public CustomerDLL()
    {
       cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString); 
    }

    public void Insert_Customer(string name, string address, string city, string state, int ZipCode)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Customer values (@name, @address, @city, @state, @ZipCode", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", state);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", Convert.ToInt32(ZipCode) ); // Line 34

        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

I am accessing this class in Customer page using this method

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // Create an instance of CustomerDll
       CustomerDLL cusdll = new CustomerDLL();

       //int zip = Convert.ToInt32(txtZip.Text);
       cusdll.Insert_Customer
            (
            txtName.Text,
            txtAddress.Text,
            txtCity.Text,
            txtState.Text,
            Convert.ToInt32(txtZip.Text)
            );

        lblMsg.Text = "Rec is inserted successfully";
        cusdll = null;
    }
```

I keep getting error

> Incorrect syntax near '@ZipCode' on line 34.

Comment: AddWithValue is expecting a string, try just taking out the Convert.ToInt

Comment: Thank you,  I tried that before posting,  and ZipCode is Int in my Database

Comment: @SteveFerg `AddWIthValue` expects a string and an object, so any type will work for the second parameter.

Comment: you missing closing parenthesis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you missed closing parenthesis after @ZipCode.

Comment: They are closed,  Thank you Sanjay

Comment: Your code above is missing it. you have got closing parenthesis after your connection 'cn', but the closing parenthesis for values( is missing in your code.

Comment: You're welcome..good to hear it solved your problem..